# javascript variable with /script value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dhtml

I have a snippet of code kinda/sorta like this:

```
<script>
var foo = "<span>Hello <script>var bar = 1;</script> world</span>" ;
</script>
```

This barfs and displays and renders the span. The problem is caused by the " value in the variable.

I have worked around it by escaping the \ and changing it to

```
<script>
var foo = "<span>Hello <script>var bar = 1;<\/script> world</span>" ;
foo.replace("\/script", "/script") ;
</script>
```

This works fine. This seems really, really hokey. There has to be a better way to do this??

Comment: I've seen this used before: `var foo = "<script>alert('hi!');<" + "/script>";`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
var foo = "<span>Hello " + "<script>var bar = 1;<\/script>" + " world</span>";
$('body').append(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Downvoted because . . . ?

Comment: It's not my downvote, but I'm guessing it's because it introduces an unnecessary dependency on jQuery to do something incredibly trivial.

Comment: Odd. The OP specified jQuery and he used jQuery in his question. Anyway, thanks for the note.

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice it was a tag. I don't see it actually used anywhere in the question though. No idea what the downvote was for then.